# getting text from Qtabewidgetitem changed in qtablewidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTablewidget` that has 3 colomumns.It've changed it's first tow columns to `label` which I've inherited from `QLabel`and it's third column is `QSpinbox`.

```
class Table:public QTableWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
 private:
 std::vector < std::vector <std::string> > food;
public slots:
 //  QString get_number();

public:
int row;
Table(QWidget* Parent=0,int row=0,int X=0,int Y=0,int weight=10,std::vector <std::vector <std::string> > food=std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >());
//  QString * get_number(Table *);
QString getorder();
};
```

Now I'm trying to get the text of third and first column for specific rows in `button` class that I have an array of `Table` objects in this class.

 `if (this->item(i,2)->text()!="0")`

But in this part of code (just for `text ()`) the programs stops running.

Can any body help me why this happens and how can I get the text?

Comment: Can you post the specific error you get?

Comment: I dont get error...It just stops running

Comment: `item(i, 2)` may have returned null?

Comment: Yes it does.But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
It should be like this:

```
string temp=dynamic_cast<QSpinBox*>(this->cellWidget(j,2))->text().toStdString();

if(temp!="0")...
```